# Is any idea how to write UT for below code?

Tags: java, junit, easymock

Is any idea how to write UT for below code?

```
    public Set<OMEntity> applyInitialDump(Map<Class<? extends Entity>, List<Entity>> centralModelRelated) {

    try {
        return _executionUnit.executeSynch(new ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel(_context, centralModelRelated));
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I try to mock _executionUnit, but how to mock the parameter(ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel) ? Thanks.

Attache some test code for reference.

```
        Map<Class<? extends Entity>,List<Entity>> centralModelRelated = new HashMap<Class<? extends Entity>, List<Entity>>();
    CentralModelUnitOfWork unitOfWork = new ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel(omContext, centralModelRelated);
    executionUnit = EasyMock.createMock(ExecutionUnit.class);
    EasyMock.expect(executionUnit.executeSynch(??????????)).andReturn(new Object()).once();;
    EasyMock.replay(executionUnit);

    centralModel.applyInitialDump(centralModelRelated);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, because the `ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel` object is instantiated within the method, it is not possible to mock that object itself.

However, the call to `executeSynch` can still be mocked using [EasyMock's Capture](http://easymock.org/api/easymock/2.4/org/easymock/Capture.html) class.

So your test would end up looking something like this:

```
Map<Class<? extends Entity>,List<Entity>> centralModelRelated = new HashMap<Class<? extends Entity>, List<Entity>>();
Capture<ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel> captureObject = new Capture<ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel>();

executionUnit = EasyMock.createMock(ExecutionUnit.class);
EasyMock.expect(executionUnit.executeSynch(EasyMock.capture(captureObject))).andReturn(new Object()).once();;
EasyMock.replay(executionUnit);

centralModel.applyInitialDump(centralModelRelated);

EasyMock.verify(executionUnit); //Don't forget to verify your mocks :)

CentralModelUnitOfWork expectedUnitOfWork = new ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel(omContext, centralModelRelated);
ApplyInitialDumpOnCentralModel actualUnitOfWork = captureObject.getValue();
//Then whatever assertion you want to make about the expected and actual unit of work.
```